# how to intercepting operating system function call

Tags: c#, operating-system, call

suppose if a program make a operating system function call and I have to intercept it how it can be done?

Comment: suppose a program make a call to run notpade then i have to intercept this call from this program

Comment: @jams: intercept _which_ call? The call to run notepad?

Comment: Uh-oh, that's going to close this question and junk my answer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API hooking in C# directly isn't possible, manipulating the stack frame requires machine code.  There is however a pretty popular library available that makes it possible from a C# program, EasyHook, download [is here](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).  Source code is available, in case you want to find out how it works.

Comment: "Support for 32- and 64-bit kernel mode hooking" Impressive!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a hook. In unmanaged code you should be able to use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Check out [EasyHook](http://code.google.com/p/easyhook-continuing-detours/) since you need to do this in C#. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/EasyHook64.aspx) article on The Code Project explains how to use it.